# What API does Facebook Flacedeck use?

Tags: facebook, silverlight-4.0

What API does flacedeck use?

http://blog.inextin.in/2010/12/flacedeck-mediacenterized-facebook.html

Does it use the same Facebook Developer toolkit or some other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had the same question, I've seen to files of installed application. It deploys with assembly named "Microsoft.Facebook, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" (Microsoft.Facebook.dll). It had puzzled me because I couldnt find any facebook framework by Microsoft. I can't say exactly what is it, but it's content (I've investigated it with Reflector tool) looks close to ["Facebook Developer Toolkit"](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/)